# Resizing AdBannerView in iOS 6.0

Tags: ios, ios6, iad, adbannerview

Using an AdBannerView, I'm confused about how to respond to device orientation changes under iOS 6.0. I haven't used iAd before, but it seems that the relevant properties and methods that were used in earlier releases are now deprecated. (These being `currentContentSizeIdentifier` and `sizeFromBannerContentSizeIdentifier:`, plus a small number of others.)

Also, two of the NSString content size identifiers constants have been deprecated and replaced by two others. But there are no properties of methods that I can see where they are used in iOS 6.0.

Can someone provide a brief tutorial or link to one that explains how this works in iOS 6.0? Existing tutorials that aren't written for iOS 6.0 don't cover this, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to update an app with ads and I've noticed some pretty unintuitive behavior myself. Look at the XIB in landscape on a 4in form factor shows the ad going only partially across the page, but when run in simulator or on device it works like expected.

As for the question, I'm still using `currentContentSizeIdentifier`(which is deprecated) and setting it as either `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait` or `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape` (which are not deprecated).

I've searched the API and don't see any other way to set it. `NSURLConnection` is another place where I've wound up using deprecated API because no replacement API exists.